# What is the best alternative for classification of a 128 dimensional vector. SVM or Random Forest?

Tags: python, svm, random-forest

Background info:
I am currently working on a facial recogntion software that uses the following:
-Python
-OpenVino Face identification model.
-Optimized DLIB's Face Recognition model. 
I currently have one face picture with the corresponding label for each person and the total amount of people is around 6000.

The problem:
After handing off a face picture of a person's face to the DLIB's neural network, the output result comes out as a 128 dimensional vector(of float64 values). The first step is to store the known pictures' vectors, I have one for each person(6000 total). The next step is to capture faces on webcam streams and identify if this picture belongs to a known person. The way to do this would be to compare the stored vectors with the captured vector. The most reasonable approach would be to use some sort of classifier; for now I am just using euclidean distance, but I am not having good results. For the amount of data I have and the problem I have exlpained, could you recommend a good classifier in this case. Would it be best to use SVM? or Random Forest?. It is important to mention again, I dont have many pictures of each person, I only have one for each.

Thanks, 
If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Are the vector values numeric (floats) or categoricals? Euclidean Distance wouldn't make any sense if the vector values are categoricals. The distance between '0' and '1' would be the same as between '1' and '3333'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the vector is made up of floats, float64

Answer (score 0):

Considering the data constraints you have, training a classifier (SVM or Random Forest) might not be the best approach as **any Machine Learning model would require to see multiple instances of a class to learn something which can be generalized**. While training a 6000 class SVM classifier would be a big challenge, Random Forest may easily find a trick to classify each sample in the training data accurately by generating specific trees but may not at all perform during testing.

I suggest that you play around more with several distance metrics - may trying plotting your points in lower dimensions and maybe look for dimensions which are more informative in doing the classification. Decision Trees are sometimes used for feature selection as well, based on this you can probably pick a few dimension and maybe then use your Euclidean Distance kind of metrics.

Apologies for giving a very subjective answer. While I cannot tell what exactly may work for your problem, I can surely say that training any of the mentioned classifiers would be a good idea for the recognition task. I hope this at least answers the question of choice you had.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anant, this is of great help. I did look up on many sites different alternatives, but got no similar results to this specific case. I was thinking of training the classifier models on the same picture, but with diferent settings, for example adding blur, rotating the image, etc. Maybe that will help me get a better result.

Comment: Hey, glad you found it helpful. While writing this answer, this came in my head as well, but I wasn't too sure if this would help a lot. OpenVino's face module has been trained to really cater to such variations already, I reckon that those 128-dimensional vector for different variation you would get, will be very similar. But there is nothing bad in trying. :)

Answer (score 0):

Deep learning based approaches are state-of-the-art studies nowadays. You cannot reach that level with SVM or Random Forest.

Dlib uses ResNet model in the background. I recommend you to switch face recognition model. VGG-Face and Google FaceNet are the most robust ones. OpenFace, Facebook DeepFace, DeepID are some other alternatives. They are all developed by tech giant and top universities.

[deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) package for python wraps all of those models.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID", "Dlib"]
obj = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
print(obj["verified"])
```

This will verify img1 and img2 are same person or different persons. You can switch the face recognition model if you change the model_name variable.

Face verification requires one picture for an identity. That's why, this satisfies your requirement as well.